# InfoPath 2013 : The form cannot be submitted. The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: infopath-rules

I have created a list form which has two text columns `Text1` and `Text2` that are populated from another list.

There are 2 fields - `Text1` and `Text2 on the InfoPath form that are populated using a data connection which is working correctly.

There are 2 `Person and Group` fields on the form. I have written down rules to populate these fields.

The rules are as follows:

Condition: None - Rule run when field is changes

> Set a fields value AccountID=Text1

This will take the text from `Text1` and convert into a username in the people picker fields.

But for some reason these rules are not working and I'm getting the error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue and convert the text values to user names?

Answer (score 1):

To populate the value of people picker field, the DisplayName, AccountId and AccountType should be set with the valid value.

DisplayName should be equal to the PreferredName of the user in his user profile

AccountId should be equal to domain\user.

AccountType should be equal to User or Group.

Reference:
http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=178